# Preventing copying from hard drive

Tags: linux, windows, security

Is there any cross-platform solution for preventing the computer's hard drives from copying to external media? I'd like to secure work machines so that data can't be transferred anywhere else (or at least all such actions are recorded), the issue is that some of those are on Windows, some are Linux. Maybe there are separate solutions for each of these?

Comment: Similar: [Prevent a hard drive from being formatted?](http://superuser.com/questions/25463/prevent-a-hard-drive-from-being-formatted?rq=1). Short answer: You can't; If you can read it, you can copy it.

Comment: Remove network cards, close the PC in a safe so nobody can access ports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry there really no such method that still allows your computer to be easily used.  If you want to do this....you'd have to NOT issue any administrative accounts, disable all the USB ports, disable the writable DVD/CDs, totally lock down the hardware so that another hard disk could not be installed, remove any networking, disable the floppies, put a password on the BIOS so that a different operating system could not be booted.  Even then, there is most likely some hole that I have missed.

Thus you can but it would be a little severe and possibly making your computer not very useable.

Comment: Well a encrypted filesystem plugs the "different operating system" hole, but yea, you will need to block via group policy all the ways to get data off (usb, upload, ect)

Answer (score 1):

As has already said, you cannot actually prevent the copying of the files. What you can do, however, is to prevent the usage of external storage medias. On linux, you can use [this link](http://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/plug-and-prey-malicious-usb-devices#3.2_Locking_down_Linux_using_UDEV).